# REST API returning http status 404 when deployed on EC2 instance on AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I have a simple spring boot app which has just 2 rest controllers and I am exporting the war for the same.
I am deploying the same war using the tomcat manager on EC2 instance on AWS, but unfortunately I am getting http status 404 when trying to hit the API.

URL that I am trying to hit is -

**[public IP shared by AWS]:[port number on which tomcat is running:8080]/[context route which is the name of my war file]/[my mapped urls]**

**[publicIP]:8080/aws-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/login/code**

**My Controller class**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("code")
    public String returnCode() {
        return "returning code";
    }

    @GetMapping("received-code")
    public String returnReceivedCode(@RequestParam String code) {
        return code;
    }

}
```

**My pom.xml**

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>aws</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
```

I tried with java version 8 as well, the tomcat version that I have on my EC2 instance is 9 (apache-tomcat-9.0.70)

I also tried getting one sample war application that tomcat shares for the testing purpose -
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/sample/

But surprisingly, this is working fine which tells me that my tomcat and java installations don't have any issues.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Spring Boot 3.0.0 requires JDK17+... also 404 means not found??

Comment: Will try to downgrade spring boot version and will give it a try

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was indeed the issue. I created a new project with spring boot 2.7.6 and it is working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As highlighted by @khmarbaise above, I was using spring boot 3.0.0 but I had java 8 installed on my EC2 instance and spring boot 3.0.0 requires java version 17+, and that is why I was getting 404 when hitting my APIs.

After downgrading my spring boot version to 2.7.6 I am able to get a corresponding response from the APIs.

Also, as mentioned by other comments regarding the use of "/", omitting the slash was not an issue as the slash is an optional parameter.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You have to add a "/" before "code"

```
@GetMapping("/code")
```

Comment: I don't think "/" is a necessary keyword, although I have tried adding "/", still facing the same issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

you forgot to add / for your path in controller methods because of you use path:

```
/logincode
```

instead `/login/code`

Comment: I don't think "/" is a necessary keyword, although I have tried adding "/", still facing the same issue.